# QGIS plugin requires a missing module: ui_gresp

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

I am developing my own plugin, the plugin manager shows the error:

> This plugin requires a missing module: ui_gresp

If i try to enable it the trace shows:

```
Couldn't load plugin gresp due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 204, in     startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users\rey/.qgis2/python/plugins\gresp\__init__.py", line 52, in classFactory
    from gresp import gresp
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\rey/.qgis2/python/plugins\gresp\gresp.py", line 29, in 
    from grespdialog import grespDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\rey/.qgis2/python/plugins\gresp\grespdialog.py", line 24, in 
    from ui_gresp import Ui_gresp
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named ui_gresp

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, d94c044

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing',         'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:\\Users\\rey/.qgis2/python', 'C:\\Users\\rey/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Ii'm not sure what this error means. I think it may be some error compiling the GUI.

Comment: hey! i found that the output of pyuic4 must be saved to a file with the same name than the input file and the .py extension, the resource suffix is needed to so it can import the resource class
like this

        pyuic4 ui_gresp.ui -o ui_gresp.py --resource-suffix=''

Answer (score 2):

i found that the output of pyuic4 must be saved to a file with the same name than the input file and the .py extension, the resource suffix is needed to so it can import the resource class
like this

```
    pyuic4 ui_gresp.ui -o ui_gresp.py --resource-suffix=''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific to QGIS. When making a PyQGIS plugin with a graphical interface, you utilize the [PyQt4 python bindings](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/) for the [Qt GUI toolkit](http://qt-project.org/).

For example, once you have drafted a dialog's *.ui file from Qt Designer, you need to 'compile' it using the [`pyuic4` command line utility (part of PyQt4 install)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html). This takes the *.ui file and generates (not really compiling) a Python module appropriate for importing into your plugin's module.

Comment: ok i have tried that too, used this two commands
`pyuic4 ui_gresp.ui -o form.ui`
`pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc`
after that the same error shows up!

Comment: Your plugin module is importing via: `from ui_gresp import Ui_gresp`, which means your resultant ui module needs to have the same name (or vice-versa), e.g. `pyuic4 -o ui_gresp.py gresp.ui` (assuming your *.ui file is named 'gresp.ui'). Please review the `pyuic4` command line options for more info (noted above). Likewise for the `pyrcc4` utility.

Answer (score 0):

i also had a problem with a qgis plugin which i'm creating for a college project...

i just did this in win 7 and it worked by combining the 2 answers and the commands are:

```
pyuic4 -o ui_gresp.py gresp.ui --resource-suffix=''

pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

now i opened my plugin and am going to edit it